# Xcode 9 performance issue

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

Have anyone tried out the new Color Asset Catalogue feature in Xcode 9. For me every time I edit something on this like adding or editing a colour asset,  I have to wait for 10-15 seconds while Xcode shows the coloured progress and does not allow any interaction.

At the same time being highly annoying, it is also highly counter-productive. I also found IB to be generally too slow after updating to Xcode 9.

Are these known issues ? Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

i asked apple about the hangs and crashes that keep on occurring on Xcode 9, and they replied:

> First, quit Xcode. And then temporarily move aside
>   UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate so that new user state is created.
>
> It can be found here
>
> path_to/$WORKSPACE.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/$USER.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
>
> (if it is an .xcodeproject, it will be deep in the project.xcworkspace
>   directory).

this worked for me with autocomplete problems and switching between files. hope it helps you out as well.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 9 is borderline unusable for me too at times. The worst is how long it takes to open/edit a storyboard file and also run the simulator. Even autocomplete and switching between code files is lagging a lot for me, much more so than past versions. I imagine Apple knows about it considering the Apple development forums are full of threads about how the newest update is unacceptable but as for how long it will take for them to do anything about it, who knows. It's an absolute nightmare for iOS developer's productivity to say the least.

My solution is to just quit Xcode when it starts getting too slow. It's a pain, obviously, but usually helps short term.

Comment: I'm also amazed that they could ship such a poor quality product.  The richest company on earth doesn't seem to care about QA.

Any time I click on anything in Interface Builder, I get the rainbow wheel for at least 5 seconds.

Comment: It's unbelievable. They really dropped the ball on this one, let's hope the next release comes soon/isn't a total catastrophe.